# CompareTo method in two separate methods

Tags: java, collections, compare

I have a class that implements the Comparable interface.
I want to sort objects by their id and by their name, but in two seperate methods.
For example, sorting by id:

```
 public int compareTo(Metro m1) {
       return this.id - m1.id;
    }
```

I also want to sort by name, which means that I have to do something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Metro m1) {
       return this.name.compareTo(m1.name);
}
```

The problem is that I can't write the same function with the same name and the same parameters, how do I do to fix this?
When I will call `Collections.sort(this.list);` on a list of objects, how is it going to identify that I want to sort my list by id or by name?

Comment: I'm not sure how others use comparable, but I only use it if my class has a natural order I want to maintain. For sorting purposes I use Collections.sort(list, Comparator)

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 so you mean compare the objects by id and then by name if their id is equal?

Comment: Yes. So long as the id is visible at the time you create the comparator.

Answer (score 5):

implementing `Comparable` is appropriate if an type has a so-called 'natural order'. That'd be an order that is the slam dunk answer to 'without any further context, how do you think these objects would be ordered'?

For example, if I ask you to order '1, 9, and 7', without further context, surely you'd go: Well, uh, I guess 1,7,9? If then later I tell you: Actually I wanted you to spell those digits out in english and then sort on the length of that, so, 1,9,7 - okay, but that's quite unexpected.

In your case, both 'by name' and 'by id' sound equally plausible.

This means that a `Metro` type has **no natural order at all**, and therefore **should not implement Comparable**.

So, how do you sort em? Fortunately, `sort()` has an overload: You can supply a Comparator object. That's how you solve this problem:

```
// requires getId() to exist as a method:
Comparator<Metro> byUnid = comparingInt(Metro::getId);
this.list.sort(byUnid);

// Works because strings do have natural order
Comparator<Metro> byName = comparing(Metro::getName)
```

It's that simple. Note that your compareTo by id method is broken - it fails for very large numbers. You should endeavour to use the `comparing`, `comparingInt`, and chaining solutions in the Comparator interface.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't have your Comparable object in a sorted collection (TreeSet, etc)
you can just provide an instance Comparator for a single sort.

Sorting by Y coord

```
List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList();        
Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point2D o1, Point2D o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.getY(), o2.getY());
        }
 });
```

Sorting by X coord

```
 Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Point2D o1, Point2D o2) {
                return Double.compare(o1.getX(), o2.getX());
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Comparator`:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparatorByName = Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name);
Comparator<MyClass> comparatorById = Comparator.comparing(a -> a.id);
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
Collections.sort(list, comparatorByName);
Collections.sort(list, comparatorById);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Metro> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Metro(5, "aziz"));
        l.add(new Metro(1, "zied"));
        l.add(new Metro(2, "ahmed"));
        Comparator<Metro> byId = new Comparator<Metro>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Metro o1, Metro o2) {
                return o1.getId() - o2.getId();
            }
        };
        l.sort(byId);
        System.out.println("by id :" + l);
        Comparator<Metro> byName = new Comparator<Metro>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Metro o1, Metro o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        };
        l.sort(byName);
        System.out.println("by name :" + l);
    }

}

class Metro {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    Metro(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + id + "," + name + "}";
    }

}
```

output :

```
by id :[{1,zied}, {2,ahmed}, {5,aziz}]
by name :[{2,ahmed}, {5,aziz}, {1,zied}]
```